# OpenCV Performance of meanStdDev

Tags: c++, performance, opencv, computer-vision

I'm currently trying to build a realtime machine vision system with a camera framerate of 30 fps (33 ms per frame) meaning that my calculations shall take a maximum of 30 ms.
Calculating the mean and the standard deviation of a picture takes 140 ms with opencv on an **Intel Core i7-4930K @ 3.40 GHz**, which is too slow.
Is this performance usual for this function and is there a way to improve the performance to get faster than the needed 30 ms, preferably without the use of Cuda?

Testcode:

```
int main()
{
    cv::Mat m = cv::Mat(1500, 2000, CV_8UC1);
    cv::Scalar n1,n2;
    int64 n3 = cv::getTickCount();
    meanStdDev(m, n1, n2);
    printf("%f\n", double(cv::getTickCount() - n3) / cv::getTickFrequency());
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you compile your program in Release mode? It took less than 10 ms on my computer.

Comment: program is compiled in release mode with visual studio 2013 and as static library

Comment: This is a very poor benchmark, you make only one measurement without any warmup. In this case, the time you obtained is dominated by all kinds of overhead unrelated to the algorithm you're actually trying to measure, and as such the result is meaningless. You need a statistically significant sample size. With 1000 iterations, the mean iteration time is around 1-2 ms on my 4930K (roughly what I would expect to see).

Comment: This is the sort of code which should benefit from AVX2, but is your OpenCV code compiled with that?